# mongoDB query through NodeJS express app always returns null in mobile browser

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, monk

I have this code that produces the desired effect in a desktop browser.

```
var express = require('express'),
    http = require('http'),
    app = express(),

    mongo = require('mongodb'),
    ObjectId = require('mongodb').ObjectID,
    ISODate = require('mongodb').ISODate,
    monk = require('monk'),
    db = monk('localhost:27017/database', {
       username : 'user',
       password : 'pwd'
    }),

    server = http.createServer(app);

app.configure(function(){
    app.use(cors());
    app.use(express.json());
});

app.get('/get-audio/:name', function(req, res){
    var hash = req.params.name,
        dbData = db.get('audio_database');
        dbData.findOne({'hash':hash}, function(e, data){
            if(e){res.send(400, e);}
            else{
                res.send(200, data);
            }
        });
});
server.listen(8080);
console.log('Listening on port 8080.');
```

In a desktop browser I get a JSON object and all is good. In mobile browsers the data object is always null. There is no error thrown. There is nothing thrown. I know this isn't a full-on REST server, but that isn't what I need. I am taking the data object and using a few attributes from the object to do some other things and not actually outputting raw data. I have deconstructed this problem so far as to find that mongo is not even returning an object. How do I make this work without implementing a full-on REST server?